# Model class init() when using Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am new to Swift and Xcode (2 months in) and I have been having a recurring problem for weeks. The problem persists throughout many areas in my app so solving it once and for all would help me sleep at night again. I store my data in firebase and display it in my app. If the data is updated or changed in firebase, it does not update in my app (except for images because I download them and use SAMCache each time.) For instance, if a class has never accessed a particular piece of data before, like a username from a user, it will be stored in something like user.username but if that user changes their username, the class will just use the old stored value; it doesn't get the new one because it doesn't know it needs to. I think it is because when I set up my model class I didn't think I would be changing the values so it looks like this:

```
        init(dictionary: [String : Any]) {

            uid = dictionary["uid"] as! String
            username = dictionary["username"] as! String
            fullName = dictionary["fullName"] as! String
```

and so on. Does this mean that I am always getting the same initial value? If so, how do I change it to look in Firebase for the updated values?

Comment: Did you go through the [Firebase Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) guide? There's a wealth of information there. Part of the power of Firebase is events - when something changed in Firebase, it sends an event to your app with what changed. To watch for events, add a listener to a node in Firebase. When a child in that node changes, like a username, an event is sent containing that node, your app can then modify the object (class, array etc) with updated data.

Comment: since before I have been using .observeSingleEvent(of: ...  now I should use .observe(.value... am I on the right track here?

Comment: YES! You are on the right track. SingleEvents are just that a single event - read the data one time. If you want to be notified of events, use .childAdded, .childChanged, or .childRemoved.  Value events are powerful as well, but they provide a LOT of data to the app at one time. The other events limited to just what was added, changed or removed.

Comment: thanks. I will keep looking in to it. Unfortunately what I am trying to do is going to take a while because I just started with Swift and Firebase